# question about transparent images within background?

Tags: html, css, web, background

I need info about uploading transparent image inside background. More precisely i need to provide new background for iphone image and then new background within iphone image. 
Thank  you for information in advance :)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please edit your question after reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you mean a transparent image with different background??

Please modify your question and be precise...

Comment: more accurate question would be: How erase background of subject in image and provide new background for that subject using html css and js, if it is possible

Comment: I think erasing the background might be possible with Photoshop..then you may specify a background Image with js and set your subject image on the background image..